# Oracle SQL - combine data from several rows

Tags: sql, oracle

i have the following table (Top row is header):

```
+-------+------+-------+------+-------+----+----+----+
| ID    | GRP  | DESC  | DEN  | NUM   | SU | CS | SW |
+-------+------+-------+------+-------+----+----+----+
| 12345 | MANX | Mango | 1    | 10    | 0  | 0  | 1  |
+-------+------+-------+------+-------+----+----+----+
| 12345 | MANX | Mango | 1    | 200   | 0  | 1  | 0  |
+-------+------+-------+------+-------+----+----+----+
| 12345 | MANX | Mango | 2667 | 10000 | 1  | 0  | 0  |
+-------+------+-------+------+-------+----+----+----+
```

**What im trying to achieve:**

```
+-------+------+-------+------+-------+----+-----+----+
| ID    | GRP  | DESC  | DEN  | NUM   | SU | CS  | SW |
+-------+------+-------+------+-------+----+-----+----+
| 12345 | MANX | Mango | 2667 | 10000 | 1  | 200 | 10 |
+-------+------+-------+------+-------+----+-----+----+
```

There are three rows returned for every ID and the reason is the values contained in the last 3 columns. **I want to combine the data for each given ID into one row.**

SU, CS and SW cannot all have 1 on the same row.If SU is 1, then CS and SW are always 0. If CS is 1 then SU and SW are always 0 and so on.

So i would like to return:

- The first 3 columns followed by
- The value in the DEN and NUM columns where SU = 1 followed by the value in the SU column
- The value in the NUM column on the row where CS = 1 followed by
- The value in the NUM column where SW = 1 or 0 if SW = 0

I have tried googling a way forward and found self joins mentioned. i have tried this and maybe due to my limited understanding i just cant get it to work. I get back many more rows of data back !

I would greatly appreciate some help on this.

cheers

**UPDATE** - Result from @vkp code

```
+-------+------+-------+------+-------+------+------+------+
| ID    | GRP  | DESC  | DEN  | NUM   | SU   | CS   | SW   |
+-------+------+-------+------+-------+------+------+------+
| 12345 | MANX | Mango | 2667 | 10000 | 1    | null | null |
+-------+------+-------+------+-------+------+------+------+
| 12345 | MANX | Mango | null | null  | null | 200  | 0    |
+-------+------+-------+------+-------+------+------+------+
| 12345 | MANX | Mango | null | null  | null | null | 1    |
+-------+------+-------+------+-------+------+------+------+
```

Comment: Terrible idea to use a reserved keyword (`desc`) as a column name. Find another name. As you try to adapt vkp's solution, make sure you don't screw up by trying to go around this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this worked:

```
select id,grp,itdesc,
 MAX(CASE WHEN su=1 or cs =1 THEN DEN END) AS DEN,
 MAX(CASE WHEN su=1 or cs =1 THEN NUM END) AS NUM,
 MAX(CASE WHEN su=1 THEN SU END) AS SU ,  -- or just  "1 AS SU" 
 MAX(CASE WHEN cs=1 THEN NUM END) AS CS,
 MAX(CASE 
   WHEN sw=1 THEN NUM  
   WHEN sw=0 THEN 0 
 END) AS SW
FROM tab
GROUP BY id,grp,itdesc
```

Answer (score 0):

For the sample data shown, this should work.

```
select id, grp, "desc", 
max(case when su = 1 then den end) den,
max(case when su = 1 then num end) num,
max(case when su = 1 then su end) su,
max(case when cs = 1 then num end) cs,
max(case when sw = 1 then num when sw = 0 then 0 end) sw
from tablename
group by id,grp,"desc"
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. For the sample data this returned the result shown in my update in the question. cheers

Comment: The additional aggregation probably won't make a difference. The original query should have worked. Something is not right, either in the way OP ran your query, or in the data.  @OP: Are you really running the query as-is?  Or are you tweaking it somehow?  In particular, did you modify the `group by` clause, or are you selecting more columns than what you are showing us?

Comment: @sstan..i think the problem was with `nvl` previously. It was evaluating the rows where sw=1 and sw=0. The edited version should resolve it.

Comment: @vkp: Even with the `nvl`, it should never have returned 3 rows.

Comment: I suspect he must have changed the query to deal with the issues caused by using `desc` as a column name... not having it (in double quotes) would cause three rows to be shown in the output.

Comment: @mathguy: That's what I was thinking too. But OP seems to have gotten the `mango` string to display correctly... OP will have to tell us what he actually did when running the query.

Comment: Hi, i didnt change the query and the column i named "desc" here is actually called "itmdesc" - (item description) but i take your point about not using reserved names.

Answer (score 0):

First of all "desc" is not a smart column name.

I would join the same table 3 times and select the values from the appropriate join. See this example (i presumed the id is some sort of unique key):

```
create table tab
( id      number(12)
, grp     varchar2(4)
, "desc"  varchar2(40)
, den     number(12)
, num     number(12)
, su      number(12)
, cs      number(12)
, sw      number(12)
);

insert into tab values ( 12345 ,'MANX','Mango', 1    , 10    , 0  , 0  , 1  );
insert into tab values ( 12345 ,'MANX','Mango', 1    , 200   , 0  , 1  , 0  );
insert into tab values ( 12345 ,'MANX','Mango', 2667 , 10000 , 1  , 0  , 0  );

select tab_su.id
,      tab_su.grp
,      tab_su."desc"
,      tab_su.den
,      tab_su.num
,      tab_cs.num as cs
,      tab_sw.num as sw
from   tab tab_su
,      tab tab_cs
,      tab tab_sw
where  tab_su.su = 1
and    tab_cs.cs = 1
and    tab_sw.sw = 1
and    tab_su.id = tab_cs.id
and    tab_su.id = tab_sw.id;
```